# what it means to host a web player unity3d file on server like dropbox loading it into facebook canvas and use backend server like GameSparks

Tags: host

I'm new to backend servers and hosting files so if you could give me a starting point just to undersand how it works.

If I can log in with a facebook profile somehow this data saved in the dropbox and if I try to log in again with a different profile I face this 
"The current user has a Facebook profile and it’s not the profile they have just tried to log in with" this from the GameSparks documentation which turns into error <"accessToken":"ACCOUNT_ALREADY_LINKED">recieved from GameSparks

Answer (score 0):

Solved 
after 12 hours I discovered that u have to disconnect from the server and reconnect 
forexample when you want to link a facebook profile the server is now connected to that user so when you want to link another profile u have to disconnect from the previous profile and connect then wait till the server is available then you could link the new profile

```
 using GameSparks.Api.Requests;
 using GameSparks.Api.Messages;
 using GameSparks.Api.Responses;
 using GameSparks.Core;

public void Awake()
{
    FB.Canvas.SetAspectRatio(9,16,FBScreen.CenterHorizontal());
    if (!FB.IsInitialized)
    {
        FB.Init(FacebookLogin);
    }
    else
    {
        FacebookLogin();
    }
}

public void FacebookLogin()
{
    if (!FB.IsLoggedIn)
    {
        FB.Login("email", GameSparksLogin);
    }
}

public void GameSparksLogin(FBResult result)
{
    StartCoroutine (GameSparksLoginProcess ());

}

IEnumerator GameSparksLoginProcess(){
    GS.Reset ();
    float i = 0;
    while (true) {
        if(!(GS.Available)){
            i += 0.2f;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
        }else{
            Debug.Log("wait: "+i+" seconds");
            break;
        }
    }
    if (FB.IsLoggedIn)
    {
        new FacebookConnectRequest().SetAccessToken(FB.AccessToken).SetDoNotLinkToCurrentPlayer(false)
            .Send((response) =>
                  {
                if (response.HasErrors)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Something failed when connectiong with Facebook");
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("GameSparks Facebook Login Successful");
                }
            });
    }
}
```